# How to divide the dataframes into new dataframes according to the specified condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe:
For example:

df =

```
Questions             Answers

Where is Amazon?       Brazil

Is he a scientist?         No

Did he stole my money?    Yes

What does your father do?  Business

He is a great player.      I don't think so.
 
She is my girlfriend.      I too agree.
```

I want to create three data frames from the above dataframe in the condition:

Condition for df1:

If the first word of the df['Questions'] is from the list:

```
# list of Yes/No verbs
yn_list = ['Do','Does','Did','do','does','did','Am','Are','Is','Was','Were','am','are','is','was','were',
           'Have','Has','Had','have','has','had','Will','Would','Shall','Should','Can','Could','May',
           'Might','will','would','shall','should','can','could','may','might']

# list of negative Yes/No verbs
yn_negative_list = ["Don't","Doesn't","Didn't","don't","doesn't","didn't","Aren't","Isn't","aren't","isn't",
                    "Wasn't","Weren't","wasn't","weren't","Haven't","Hasn't","Hadn't","haven't","hasn't",
                    "hadn't","Won't","Wouldn't","won't","wouldn't","Shan't","shan't","Shouldn't","Can't",
                    "Couldn't","shouldn't","can't","couldn't","may not","May not","Mightn't","mightn't"]
```

Condition for df2:

If the first word of the df['Questions'] is from the list:

```
wh_list = ['who','where','what','when','why','whom','which','whose','how']
```

Condition for df3:

If the sentence ends with a '.' sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1 = df[df["Questions"].str.split(n=1).str[0].isin(yn_list + yn_negative_list)]
print(df1)
print()


df2 = df[df["Questions"].str.lower().str.split(n=1).str[0].isin(wh_list)]
print(df2)
print()

df3 = df[df["Questions"].str.endswith(".")]
print(df3)
print()
```

Prints:

```
                Questions Answers
1      Is he a scientist?      No
2  Did he stole my money?     Yes

                   Questions   Answers
0           Where is Amazon?    Brazil
3  What does your father do?  Business

               Questions            Answers
4  He is a great player.  I don't think so.
5  She is my girlfriend.       I too agree.
```

Comment: Simple and direct indeed. I think it would help to create a boolean function for these complex queries. `def question(row): return row.question.startswith(tuple(yn_list+yn_negative_list))` specially you have many of these and if they involve any more columns ( like answers )

Answer (score 5):

Your 3rd condition:

```py
df[df['Question'].str.endswith('.')]

                Question                   Answer
4  He is a great player.        I don't think so.
5  She is my girlfriend.             I too agree.
```

2nd condition:

```py
df[df['Question'].str.lower().str.startswith(tuple(wh_list))]

                    Question         Answer
0           Where is Amazon?         Brazil
3  What does your father do?       Business
```

And the 1st condition:

```py
df[df['Question'].str.lower().str.startswith(tuple(yn_list+yn_negative_list))]

                 Question       Answer
1      Is he a scientist?           No
2  Did he stole my money?          Yes
```

Comment: TIL that `.str.startswith` accepts a tuple. But I can't find anything in [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) +1